# drupal ubercart product kit and views

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, ubercart

hey.
i am working with drupal 6, ubercart 2, views 2.

i have several products that are related to a product kit.
i want to define a view that will show all the kits and their products.
but when defining my view, i cant add a relationship between the product kit and the products that are member in this kit.
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's still relevant, but looks like node relations fields in CCK are perfect for your task. Views nicely work with them too. Just create one for your product type and set it to point to product kits.

This way you would get a many-to-one relation between products and product kits.